# SN74HC595 multiplexing with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, multiplexer, led-matrix

I'd appreciate some advice on a basic circuit. I am using two SN74HC595 ICs to multiplex 64 LED groups, but I need different numbers of LEDs per group, and the total current draw for all the LEDs will be over the SN74HC595 limit of 70 mA (and 6 mA per channel).

So I plan to feed the SN74HC595 output to MOSFETs. One SN74HC595 would control 8 PMOS on the high side, and the other SN74HC595 8 NMOS on the low side. The MOSFETs would be 3401 and 3402 logic level so they should work at 3V3.

- Is this a reasonable circuit?
- Does there need to be a pulldown resistor on the NMOS gate, and a pullup to 3V3 on the PMOS gate?
- Is it reasonable to switch these mosfets directly with a 1kΩ resistor from the SN74HC595, or should I have some sort of gate driver, particularly for the PMOS so it can switch 5 V?

For clarity I've only shown one group of LEDs out of 64, and one MOSFET each out of 8+8.

[image: Selected components.]

Comment: Have a look at the P-MOS body diode. Without level shifting, powering the LEDs from a higher voltage looks pointless.

Comment: (Check out the MAX7221.)

Comment: @greybeard
I see the pmos body diode looks wrong. Should the source and drain be switched around on the pmos (so pin 2 is high side, and pin 3 lower side)? And by level shifting, could you clarify please? What I need here is more to draw higher current than the IC can provide, but I only need 2ish volts for the LEDs.

Comment: Think G, S, D instead of 123. Yes, as a "high-side switch", the source of a P-channel MOS should be connected to the positive side of the power supply.

Comment: @greybeard - As for the MAX7221 :D I actually have this project fully working with a MAX7221, it's a great chip, but sadly it only has 16 levels of brightness control, and I need a way to electronically control the brightness of the LEDs to a much wider range (very dim in the dark, very bright in the sun). I tried adding a PWM on top of the MAX7221 channels, but didn't get it working the way I wanted.

Comment: Without change, \$V_{GS}\$ would be 1.7 Volts with SEG_A high, and the P-MOS "on" - you need to "shift" the gate voltage level.

Comment: @greybeard should I pullup the gate to 5v, and then use an nmos or a bjt for switching the gate to 0v?

Comment: The direction is right, but are you sure you can/should pull up an 74HC output to more than \$V_{CC}+.7\$ Volts? I've experimented with an about 1:1 voltage divider with a small signal diode or two thrown in. Alternatives include using a 74HC**T** part powered from 5 Volts.

Comment: @greybeard Sorry, I meant 3v3 to the gate of an additional NMOS, which would force the gate of the PMOS to 0v (with a 10K pullup to 5v). The problem is that the 74HC is being controlled by a 3v3 microcontroller, and I didn't want to level shift the SPI signals, but I guess maybe it's simpler to do that in the end. Thank you!

Comment: (I wouldn't give up using a working MAX7221 assembly lightly. Operating from a 10k \$R_{SET}\$? Consider swapping in 9.1k in series to 68k, controllably shunted by a suitable switch for a "linear 1:8 current selection" on top of the 7221's 1-15 16th PWM.)

Comment: @greybeard That's a good idea, but I have a 100K pot on the Rset, and the lowest current setting still results in LEDs that are too bright. What I could try is having a parallel resistor and MOSFET in series with each SEG, and then I could chose the current path to the LED (through the MOSFET or resistor), to achieve an additional dimming. Maybe I'll try that, given the MAX7221 works great otherwise.

Comment: `lowest current setting still results in LEDs that are too bright.` at 1/16th PWM - a shame. One idea would seem to ask another question about dimming a display deeper than a MAX7221 seems to allow.

Comment: There are power versions of the 595 with integrated MOSFETs. This could help the low side driver,  STPIC6D595, NPIC6C596A, TPIC6C595